# How do I fix this syntax error with Python serial?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

This is the error:

> AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'

I installed [pySerial](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/) and uninstalled `serial`.

```py
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1d11', 9600)
ser.write('5')
```

So what is the problem? My Python is 3.6. My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Is your file called _serial.py_? If so, rename it and remove directory \_\_pycache__.

Comment: That's an attribute error, not a syntax error.

Comment: how did you install pyserial? please rephrase your question. What do you mean with `uninstall serial`?

Comment: @DyZ  you are right . i rename the file and it is working now

Comment: @bluesmonk i ,mean i remove the serial library and install pyserial

Comment: @ElSayedMohamed so you *do* have a file called serial.py, which has nothing to do with `pyserial` at all. I am guessing that you have an import conflict, meaning that python is importing your module `serial.py` instead of `pyserial` (which is imported the same way). @DyZ is right, and the chosen answer is not even addressing the problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's working for me. Try it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import serial
from time import sleep
import math

port = '/dev/ttyAMA0'
baud = 9600
timeout = 5

ser = serial.Serial(port=port, baudrate=baud, timeout=timeout)
```

You can also refer to the link https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=87465